# Unexpected Blank lines in python output to Windows console

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I have a little program that prints out a direcory structure.
It works fine except when the direcory names contain german umlaut characters.
In this case int prints a blank line after the directory line.

I'm running Python 3.50 on Windows 7 64bit.

This Code ...

```
class dm():
...
    def print(self, rootdir=None, depth=0):

    if rootdir is None:
        rootdir = self.initialdir

    if rootdir in self.dirtree:
        print('{}{} ({} files)'.format('   '*depth, 
                                    rootdir, 
                                    len(self.dirtree[rootdir]['files'])))
        for _dir in self.dirtree[rootdir]['dirs']:
            self.print(os.path.join(rootdir, _dir), depth+1)
    else:
        pass
```

...produces the following output:

```
B:\scratch (11 files)
   B:\scratch\Test1 (3 files)
   B:\scratch\Test1 - Kopie (0 files)
   B:\scratch\Test1 - Übel (0 files)

   B:\scratch\Test2 (3 files)
      B:\scratch\Test2\Test21 (0 files)
```

This is so with codepage set to 65001. If i change the codepage to e.g. 850 then the blank line disappears but of course the "Ü" isn't printed correctly.

The structure self.dirtree is a dict of dicts of lists, is parsed with os.walk and seems OK.

Python or Windows? Any suggestions?
Marvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several bugs when using codepage 65001 (UTF-8) -- all of which are due to the Windows console (i.e. conhost.exe), not Python. The best solution is to avoid this buggy codepage, and instead use the wide-character API, such as by loading [win_unicode_console](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console).

You're experiencing a bug that exists in the legacy console that was used prior to Windows 10. (It's still available in Windows 10 if you select the option "Use legacy console".) The console decodes the UTF-8 buffer to UTF-16 and reports back that it writes `b'\xc3\x9c'` (i.e. `"Ü"` encoded as UTF-8) as one character, but it's supposed to report back the number of *bytes* that it writes, which is two. Python's buffered `sys.stdout` sees that apparently one byte wasn't written, so it dutifully writes the last byte of the line again, which is `b'\n'`. That's why you get an extra newline. The result can be far worse if a written buffer has many non-ASCII characters, especially codes above U+07FF that get encoded as three UTF-8 bytes.

---

There's a worse bug if you try to paste `"Ü"` into the interactive REPL. This bug is still present even in Windows 10. In this case a process is reading the console's wide-character (UTF-16) input buffer encoded as UTF-8. The console does the conversion via `WideCharToMultiByte` with a buffer that assumes one Unicode character is a single byte in the target codepage. But that's completely wrong for UTF-8, in which one UTF-16 code may map to as many as three bytes. In this case it's two bytes, and the console only allocates one byte in the translation buffer. So `WideCharToMultiByte` fails, but does the console try to increase the translation buffer size? No. Does it fail the call? No. It actually returns back that it 'successfully' read 0 bytes. To Python's REPL that signals `EOF` (end of file), so the interpreter just exits as if you had entered `Ctrl+Z` at the prompt.

Comment: Thanks for your exhaustive answer eryksun.

Fortunately my code doesn't depend on the printing (it's for debugging only). However I will try out your suggestion with win_unicode_console.

Marvin